# problem with code "[ccls] array type 'char [40]' is not assignable"

Tags: c, struct, variable-assignment, swap, c-strings

I was working on a code that used structures to work, the code was supposed to get sentences from a file and organize them in a different file. everything was working correctly but then I was told that the way that I did my structure was wrong instead of doing

```
typedef struct s_words {
   char * str; //word
   int count; //number of times word occurs
   struct s_words * next; //pointer to next word
}words;
```

and I was told to change it to

```
typedef struct s_word {
    char word[40];
    int count;
    struct s_word* next;
} words;
```

when I did this a lot of problems arise and although I believe I'm almost done will all of them there is one that I can't really solve. the problem is "[ccls] array type 'char [40]' is not assignable"
in the following part

```
while (temp -> next != NULL) {

         if (strcmp(temp -> word, temp -> next -> word) > 0) {
            printf("|cmp1: %s \t", temp -> word);
            printf("cmp2: %s \t", temp -> next -> word);
            printf("cmp: %d \t", strcmp(temp -> word, temp -> next -> word));

            swapTemp = temp -> word;
            temp -> word = temp -> next -> word;
            temp -> next -> word = swapTemp;
            printf("next word: %s| \t", temp -> next -> word);
            temp = * wordList;
         }
         // else {
         printf("%s ", temp -> word);
         // printf("next word: %s \t", temp->next->str);
         temp = temp -> next;
         // }
      }
```

the following 2

```
temp -> word = temp -> next -> word;
temp -> next -> word = swapTemp;
```

have the problem

the full code is bellow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// structure defanition of a node
typedef struct s_word {
  char word[40];
  int count;
  struct s_word *next;
} words;

// declaring head and tail pointers of the stopword list
words*stopwordHead = NULL, *stopwordLast = NULL;

words * create_words(char * word); 

// method to add the stopwords read from the file to a list
void add_stopWord()
{  
   char buff[255]; //creating char array to store data of file  

   FILE *myFile = fopen("stopwords.txt", "r"); // open the stopwords.txt file

   // check for errors while file opening
   if (myFile == 0) 
   {
      printf("Stopword file not opened\n");
      exit(0);
   } 

   words *temp = stopwordHead;
   // read each word from the file
  while (fscanf(myFile, "%s",buff) != EOF)
  {   
      // and add it to the list

      if (stopwordHead ==  NULL) 
      {
         stopwordHead = stopwordLast =  create_words(buff);
         
      }

      // create new node with current word as its value
      temp = create_words(buff);

      // add new node to tail of the list and update the tail pointer of the list
      stopwordLast->next = temp;
      stopwordLast = temp;    
  }

  fclose(myFile); // close the file
}

words* add_word(words ** wordList, char * word) {

   words *tem  = stopwordHead;
   int flag = 0;
  
   // check wheter  current word read from text.txt is a stopword or not
   // if yes, then set flag = 1
   while(tem != NULL)
   {
      if(strcmp(word, tem->word) == 0)
      {
         flag = 1;
         break;
      }
      tem = tem->next;
   }
   // if flag == 1, thenn don't add the word to the wordList
   if(flag)
      return *wordList;

   if (! *wordList) {
      /* handle EMPTY list */
      printf("NEW LIST\n");
      return *wordList = create_words(word);
   }


   words *temp = *wordList;
   //+ search if word exists in the list; if so, make found=1
   while (temp -> next != NULL) {
      /* iterate while temp->next != NULL */

      if (strcmp(temp -> word, word) == 0) { //+use strcmp command
         temp -> count = temp -> count + 1; //+increment count;
         return *wordList;
      } else
         temp = temp -> next; //+update temp
   }

   words * newWord = create_words(word);
   if (NULL != newWord) {
      /* insert at TAIL of list */
      temp -> next = newWord;

      printf(" NEW WORD: %s\n ", newWord -> word);

      temp = * wordList;
      char * swapTemp;
      while (temp -> next != NULL) {

         if (strcmp(temp -> word, temp -> next -> word) > 0) {
            printf("|cmp1: %s \t", temp -> word);
            printf("cmp2: %s \t", temp -> next -> word);
            printf("cmp: %d \t", strcmp(temp -> word, temp -> next -> word));

            swapTemp = temp -> word;
            temp -> word = temp -> next -> word;
            temp -> next -> word = swapTemp;
            printf("next word: %s| \t", temp -> next -> word);
            temp = * wordList;
         }
         // else {
         printf("%s ", temp -> word);
         // printf("next word: %s \t", temp->next->str);
         temp = temp -> next;
         // }
      }
      printf("next word: %s \t", temp -> word);
   }
   return newWord;
}

int concordance() {

   words * mywords; //+head of linked list containing words
    // call the method to create a list with stopwords
   mywords = NULL;
   char * delim = ". ,:;\t\n";

   int counter = 0;
   FILE * myFile;
   FILE * myOutput;

   myFile = fopen("text.txt", "r"); //+first parameter is input file
   if (myFile == 0) {
      printf("file not opened\n");
      return 1;
   } else {
      printf("file opened \n");
   }

   //+start reading file character by character;
   //+when word has been detected; call the add_word function

   int ch = 0, word = 1, k = 0;
   char thisword[100];
   while ((ch = fgetc(myFile)) != EOF) {
      /* for each char */
      if (strchr(delim, ch)) {
         /* check if delim */
         if (word == 1) {
            /* if so, terminate word, reset */
            word = 0;
            thisword[k] = '\0';

            printf("\nadd_word (mywords, %s)\n", thisword);
            /* do NOT overwrite list address each time,
             * you must send ADDRESS of list to add_word
             * to handle EMPTY list case.
             */
            if (add_word( &mywords, thisword))
               printf(" added: %s\n", mywords -> word);
            else
               fprintf(stderr, "error: add_word failed.\n");

            k = 0;
         }
      } else {
         /* if not delim, add char to string, set word 1 */
         word = 1;
         thisword[k++] = tolower(ch); /* make ch lowercase */
      }
   }
   if (word == 1) {
      /* handle non-POSIX line-end */
      thisword[k] = '\0';
      //add thisword into the list
      printf("\nadd_word (mywords, %s) (last)\n", thisword);
      if (add_word( & mywords, thisword)) /* same comment as above */
         printf(" added: %s\n", mywords -> word);
      else
         fprintf(stderr, "error: add_word failed.\n");
   }

   words * currword;
   printf("printing list\n");

   //+Traverse list and print each word and its count to outputfile
   //+output file is second parameter being passed

   myOutput = fopen("concordance.txt", "w+"); //+first parameter is input file
   if (myOutput == 0) {
      printf("output file not opened \n");
      return 1;
   } else {
      printf("output file opened \n");
   }

   currword = mywords;

   while (currword != NULL) {
      /* just test currword here */
      currword = currword -> next;
      counter++;
   }
   fprintf(myOutput, "There are %d distinct words in the text file:\n", counter);
   currword = mywords;

   while (currword != NULL) {
      /* just test currword here */
      //add word name then word count to file, then move to next
      fprintf(myOutput, "%s %d \n", currword -> word, currword -> count);
      printf("%s ", currword -> word);
      currword = currword -> next;
   }

   putchar('\n');
   return 1;
}

int stopwords() {

   words * mywords; //+head of linked list containing words
   add_stopWord();
    // call the method to create a list with stopwords
   mywords = NULL;
   char * delim = ". ,:;\t\n";

   int counter = 0;
   FILE * myFile;
   FILE * myOutput;

   myFile = fopen("text.txt", "r"); //+first parameter is input file
   if (myFile == 0) {
      printf("file not opened\n");
      return 1;
   } else {
      printf("file opened \n");
   }

   //+start reading file character by character;
   //+when word has been detected; call the add_word function

   int ch = 0, word = 1, k = 0;
   char thisword[100];
   while ((ch = fgetc(myFile)) != EOF) {
      /* for each char */
      if (strchr(delim, ch)) {
         /* check if delim */
         if (word == 1) {
            /* if so, terminate word, reset */
            word = 0;
            thisword[k] = '\0';

            printf("\nadd_word (mywords, %s)\n", thisword);
            /* do NOT overwrite list address each time,
             * you must send ADDRESS of list to add_word
             * to handle EMPTY list case.
             */
            if (add_word( &mywords, thisword))
               printf(" added: %s\n", mywords -> word);
            else
               fprintf(stderr, "error: add_word failed.\n");

            k = 0;
         }
      } else {
         /* if not delim, add char to string, set word 1 */
         word = 1;
         thisword[k++] = tolower(ch); /* make ch lowercase */
      }
   }
   if (word == 1) {
      /* handle non-POSIX line-end */
      thisword[k] = '\0';
      //add thisword into the list
      printf("\nadd_word (mywords, %s) (last)\n", thisword);
      if (add_word( & mywords, thisword)) /* same comment as above */
         printf(" added: %s\n", mywords -> word);
      else
         fprintf(stderr, "error: add_word failed.\n");
   }

   words * currword;
   printf("printing list\n");

   //+Traverse list and print each word and its count to outputfile
   //+output file is second parameter being passed

   myOutput = fopen("concordance_wo_stop_words.txt", "w+"); //+first parameter is input file
   if (myOutput == 0) {
      printf("output file not opened \n");
      return 1;
   } else {
      printf("output file opened \n");
   }

   currword = mywords;

   while (currword != NULL) {
      /* just test currword here */
      currword = currword -> next;
      counter++;
   }
   fprintf(myOutput, "There are %d distinct words in the text file:\n", counter);
   currword = mywords;

   while (currword != NULL) {
      /* just test currword here */
      //add word name then word count to file, then move to next
      fprintf(myOutput, "%s %d \n", currword -> word, currword -> count);
      printf("%s ", currword -> word);
      currword = currword -> next;
   }

   putchar('\n');
   return 1;
}

int main() {
   concordance();
   stopwords();

   return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Need to use `strcpy` not assignment for arrays with strings in them.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator.

For example instead of this code snippet

```
       swapTemp = temp -> word;
        temp -> word = temp -> next -> word;
        temp -> next -> word = swapTemp;
```

you need to write

```
     char swapTemp[ sizeof( temp->word ) ];
     strcpy( swapTemp, temp->word );
     strcpy( temp->word, temp->next->word );
     strcpy( temp->next->word, swapTemp );
```

I have not looked through all your code but for example this code snippet

```
  if (stopwordHead ==  NULL) 
  {
     stopwordHead = stopwordLast =  create_words(buff);
     
  }

  // create new node with current word as its value
  temp = create_words(buff);

  // add new node to tail of the list and update the tail pointer of the list
  stopwordLast->next = temp;
  stopwordLast = temp;
```

is wrong and moreover can invoke undefined behavior because there is used the null pointer `stopwordLast` to access memory in the expression `stopwordLast->next`. And initially `create_words` is called two times for the same string stored in the array `buff`.